# Ruby difference between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

I need to check the difference between two date and check if there is 24 hours or more. I am having trouble in calling the `to_time` method of the date object. This `to_time` method is turning the minutes and seconds if the current date to 00:00:00.

Example:

```
date = Date.rfc3339('2017-08-16T17:55:49.000-03:00')
=> #<Date: 2017-08-16 ((2457982j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
date.to_time
2017-08-16 00:00:00 -0300 
(( Date.today.to_time - date.to_time)/3600).round
=> 24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` does not include `Time`. Use `DateTime` instead.

```
require 'date'

dt = DateTime.rfc3339('2017-08-16T17:55:49.000-03:00')    
puts (Time.now - dt.to_time)/(60*60) > 24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
datetime_1 = DateTime.parse("2017-08-17T13:36:03-04:00")
datetime_2 = DateTime.parse("2017-08-16T13:33:03-04:00")
greatest_datetime = [datetime_1, datetime_2].max
smallest_datetime = [datetime_1, datetime_2].min
(greatest_datetime - 1.day) > smallest_datetime
```